# Using returned EitherT in haskell program

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, either, io-monad

I'm trying to use the "citation-resolve" package in a Haskell project I'm working on, but I'm having trouble getting my head around using EitherT's in real code. I get that they're monad transformers, and I think I understand what that means, however I can't seem to actually work out how to use them. The toy example that represents what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
module Main where
import Text.EditDistance
import Text.CSL.Input.Identifier
import Text.CSL.Reference
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class 
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either 

main = do
    putStrLn "Resolving definition"
    let resRef = runEitherT $ resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595"
    case resRef of 
                Left e -> do 
                    putStrLn ("Got error: "++ e)
                Right ref -> do
                    putStrLn ("Added reference to database: "++ (show ref))
```

Here, `resolveEither` has the type:

```
resolveEither :: (HasDatabase s,
                  Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m,
                  mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState s m)
                   => String -> EitherT String m Reference
```

and `runEitherT $ resolveEither "ref"` has the type:

```
runEitherT $ resolveEither "ref"
   :: (HasDatabase s,
       Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m,
       mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState s m)
         => m (Either String Reference)
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
Main.hs:10:34:
    No instance for (Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO (Either [Char]))
      arising from a use of ‘resolveEither’
    In the first argument of ‘runEitherT’, namely
      ‘(resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595")’
    In the expression:
      runEitherT (resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595")
    In an equation for ‘resRef’:
        resRef = runEitherT (resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595")
```

Which I have no idea how to resolve, or work around.

Any help would be appreciated, especially pointers to tutorials dealing with monad transformers from a usage perspective, not an implementation one.

Edit:

To reflect the comments on answers by dfeuer and Christian, I still get errors if I change main to the following:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Resolving definition"
    resRef <- runEitherT (resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595")
    case resRef of 
                Left e -> do 
                    putStrLn ("Got error: "++ e)
                Right ref -> do
                    putStrLn ("Added reference to database: "++ (show ref))
```

The error I get now is:

```
No instance for (MonadState s0 IO)
  arising from a use of ‘resolveEither’
In the first argument of ‘runEitherT’, namely
  ‘(resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595")’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  resRef <- runEitherT (resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595")
In the expression:
  do { putStrLn "Resolving definition";
       resRef <- runEitherT (resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595");
       case resRef of {
         Left e -> do { ... }
         Right ref -> do { ... } } }
```

I'm editing my question as well as commenting, as nice code formatting is substantially easier here than in a comment.

Comment: To rephrase dfeuer's answer, could you try replacing `let resRef = runEitherT {-...-}` with `resRef <- runEitherT {-...-}`? If that fixes it and you don't understand, I can try to explain.

Comment: As reflected in my edit, I've tried that, but still got type errors. I *think* I know why that should work, in that it "unwraps" one layer of monad (i.e. IO) from it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered one of the shortcomings of the `mtl` class-based approach: intimidating type errors. I think it'll be helpful to imagine what the situation would look like with normal `transformers`-based monad transformers. I hope this will also help you get your feet with monad transformers in general. (It looks like you already understand most of this, by the way; I'm just spelling it out.)

Giving the types is a great way to start. Here's what you had:

```
resolveEither :: (HasDatabase s,
                  MonadIO m,
                  MonadState s m)
                   => String -> EitherT String m Reference
```

There's a type hidden in the constraints, `s`, which came back to bite you a little later. The constraints, roughly speaking, express the following: `s` has a database (whatever that means in context); the monad or monad stack `m` has `IO` at its base, and somewhere in the monad stack `m` is a `StateT s` layer. The simplest monad stack `m` satisfying those properties would be `HasDatabase s => StateT s IO`. So we could write this:

```
resolveEither' :: HasDatabase s
                  => String -> EitherT String (StateT s IO) Reference
resolveEither' = resolveEither
```

All we've done is specify the type of `m` so it's no longer a variable. We don't *need* to do that as long as we satisfy the class constraints.

Now it's clearer that there are two layers of monad transformers. Since our main function is in the `IO` monad, we want to end up with a value of type `IO`, which we can "run", for instance using `<-` in `do` notation. I think of it as "stripping away" layers of the monad transformer, from out to in. (This is what "using" monad transformers boils down to.)

For `EitherT`, there's a function `runEitherT :: EitherT e m a -> m (Either e a)`. See how the `m` moves from "inside" the `EitherT` to "outside"? For me, that's the critical intuitive observation. Similarly for `StateT`, there's `runStateT :: StateT s m a -> s -> m (a, s)`.

(Incidentally, both are defined as record accessors, which is idiomatic but causes them to show up a bit oddly in Haddock and with the "wrong" type signature; it took me a while to learn to look in the "Constructor" section on Haddocks and mentally add the `EitherT e m a ->` etc. to the front of the signature.)

So this adds up to a general solution, which you've basically worked out: we need an appropriate value of type `s` (which I'll call `s`), then we can use `flip runStateT s . runEitherT $ resolveEither "ref"` which has type `IO ((Either String Reference), s)`. (Assuming I've kept the types straight in my head, which I probably didn't. I had forgotten `flip` the first time.) We can then pattern-match or use `fst` to get to the `Either`, which seems to be what you really want.

If you'd like me to explicate the errors GHC was giving you, I'd be glad. Informally, it was saying that you weren't "running" or stripping off all the monad transformers. More precisely, it was observing that `IO` wasn't something like `StateT s IO`. By using `runStateT` and `runEitherT`, you force or constrain the type such that the class constraints end up satisfied. This is kind of confusing when you get things slightly wrong.

Oh, regarding an idiomatic way to write the solution: I'm not sure that a separate `retEither` function would be idiomatic here, because it looks like it's meddling with global state, i.e. opening some sort of database file. It depends what the library's idiom is like.

Also, by using `evalStateT`, you're implicitly throwing away the state after evaluation, which may or may not be a bad idea. Does the library expect you to reuse the database connection?

Finally, you have some extra parentheses and some missing type signatures; [`hlint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) will help you with those.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I needed to know! Thanks! I think I was starting to understand how `runEitherT` moves a monad outside the EitherT, but I didn't realise that there was _another_ monad that needed stripping as well. I've marked your answer as accepted, as I think although mine provides (more or less) working code, yours provides a much better explanation of how to deal with code like this in general.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to *pattern match* on `resRef` when what you probably want to do is *execute* it and pattern match on the result.

So you should try this:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Resolving definition"
    resRef <- runEitherT $ resolveEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595"
    case resRef of 
                Left e -> do
```

Comment: For some reasons that still gives similar errors:

if I modify `Main` to:

`main = do resRef <- runEitherT (resolveEither "...") case resRef of Left e -> do `
I get the error:

` No instance for (MonadState s0 IO)
      arising from a use of ‘resolveEither’
    In the first argument of ‘runEitherT’, namely
      ‘(resolveEither "...")’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      resRef <- runEitherT (resolveEither "...")
    In the expression:
      do { resRef <- runEitherT (resolveEither "...");
           case resRef of {
             Left e -> do { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I think I've worked out a solution to my original problem, which was getting a value of the type `IO (Either String Reference)` from the function `resolveEither` (which it does for the `resolveDef` function it provides).

So, `resolveEither` returns a type of

```
(HasDatabase s, MonadIO m, MonadState s m) => String -> EitherT String m Reference
```

which we can transform to one of type

```
(HasDatabase s, MonadIO m, MonadState s m) => String -> m (Either String Reference)
```

using `runEitherT . resolveEither`. This was where I'd got up to when I asked the question. From there, i tried looking at the source to see how the library extracted a `Reference` type from the function `resolveEither`. The library uses the following function:

```
resolve :: (MonadIO m, MonadState s m, HasDatabase s) => String -> m Reference
resolve = liftM (either (const emptyReference) id) . runEitherT . resolveEither
```

however, we want to preserve the either, i.e. removing `liftM (either (const emptyReference) id)`

This however gets us back to where we started, so I looked at the source again, and worked out how this function is used. In the library, the function is used within the following, which transforms the output type of `resolve` from a value of type `(MonadIO m, MonadState s m, HasDatabase s) => m Reference` to one of type `IO Reference`:

```
resolveDef :: String -> IO Reference
resolveDef url = do
  fn <- getDataFileName "default.db"
  let go = withDatabaseFile fn $ resolve url
  State.evalStateT go (def :: Database)
```

We can replace `resolve` in the previous with `runEitherT.resolveEither` to get a function that returns a `IO (Either String Reference)`:

```
retEither s = do
    fn <- getDataFileName "default.db"
    let go = withDatabaseFile fn $ ( (runEitherT.resolveEither) s)
    State.evalStateT go (Database Map.empty)
```

(I've replaced `(def :: Database)` with `(Database Map.empty)` as def is only defined internally in `citation-resolve`)

The overall solution then becomes:

```
module Main where
import Text.EditDistance
import Text.CSL.Input.Identifier.Internal  
import Text.CSL.Input.Identifier
import Text.CSL.Reference
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
import Control.Monad.State as State
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

main = do
    putStrLn "Resolving definition"
    resRef <- retEither "doi:10.1145/2500365.2500595" 
    case resRef of 
                Left e -> putStrLn ("Got error: "++ e)
                Right ref -> putStrLn ("Added reference to database: "++ (show ref))

retEither s = do
    fn <- getDataFileName "default.db"
    let go = withDatabaseFile fn $ ((runEitherT.resolveEither) s)
    State.evalStateT go (Database Map.empty)
```

Which solves the original problem!

Any pointers on style, or ways of simplifying the whole process would however be very much appreciated.

Comment: About style: I would add type signatures (at least to `retEither`). Also, `withDatabaseFile fn $ ((runEitherT.resolveEither) s)` is equivalent to `withDatabaseFile fn . runEitherT . resolveEither $ s`.

Comment: Ah, of course - I forgot the type signatures, as I was just trying to get something working, and the more bracket averse version looks good as well. Thanks!